# Помогите исправить алгоритм нахождения значений, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В

Tags: c#

p.s сортировка пузырьком и двоичный поиск нужны по заданию

Он выводит значения, которые находятся и в A, и в B, но нужно только которые находятся в А[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
    
namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] BubbleSort(int[] mas) //сортировка пузырьком, по заданию
        {
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < mas.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (mas[i] > mas[j])
                    {
                        temp = mas[i];
                        mas[i] = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return mas;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) //двоичный поиск, по заданию 
        {
            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            int mas_size = 100, m, lowerBound, upperBound;
            int[] a = new int[mas_size];
            int[] b = new int[mas_size];
            int[] c = new int[mas_size];
            int last_zap = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                a[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
                b[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }
            time.Start();
            a = BubbleSort(a);
            b = BubbleSort(b);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                lowerBound = 0;
                upperBound = mas_size;
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    if (c[last_zap - 1] == a[j])
                        continue;
                }

                while (last_zap < 100) //НАХОЖДЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЙ МАССИВА А, КОТОРЫХ НЕТ В МАССИВЕ Б
                {
                    m = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                    if (m >= mas_size)
                        break;
                    if (a[j] < b[m])
                        upperBound = m - 1;
                    else if (a[j] > b[m])
                        lowerBound = m + 1;
                    else
                    {
                        c[last_zap] = b[m];
                        last_zap++;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (lowerBound > upperBound || m == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            time.Stop(); //установить время работы программы, по заданию
            Console.WriteLine("Продолжительность работы: " + time.Elapsed);
            if (mas_size <= 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("a[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, a[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("b[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, b[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n Элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В:\n");
                    for (int j = 0; j < last_zap; j++)
                    {
                        { Console.Write(c[j] + " ");
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Не соответствуют условию\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что не работает конкретно? Поиск не работает? Зачем Вам двоичный поиск? Он нужен для поиска индекса элемента.

Comment: `//НАХОЖДЕНИЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЙ` - индексов или самих значений? Текст задания в секрете?

Comment: Двоичный поиск требуется для задания, находим сами значения массива

Comment: Для выполнения задания необходимо использовать два одномерных массива целых чисел А[M] и В[N] (М и N – произвольные целые числа, не превышающие 2^14). Инициализируйте исходные массивы данными, после чего отсортируйте массивы с использованием алгоритма, указанного в вашем задании. Создайте одномерный массив С, который содержит элементы, отвечающие условию задания, в одном экземпляре (без повторений). Сравните время работы программы при следующих размерах исходных массивов: 100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 15000 элементов.

Comment: Задание: элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В. Алгоритм сортировки: пузырьком. Алгоритм поиска: двоичный

Comment: `Двоичный поиск требуется для задания, находим сами значения массива` - неверно, двоичный поиск - это когда ты алгоритму даешь число, а он возвращает тебе его индекс в массиве или не возвращает, если элемента нет. Вы наверное неверно поняли задание. Либо двоичный поиск используется только чтобы определить, есть элемент или нет.

Comment: @AlAvenger, не работает поиск чисел в массиве А, которых нет в Б

Answer (score 0):

Выделите бинарный поиск в отдельную функцию.
Возьмите такую его реализацию, которая возвращает индекс вставки элемента

[пример](https://brestprog.by/topics/binsearch/)

Если на шарп перевести, будет примерно так:

```
//l == r == искомый индекс
//Если искомого элемента не было в массиве,
//бинарный поиск найдёт следующий после него элемент.
static int binsearch_array(int[] a, int val, int l, int r) {

   while (r > l) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;    //целочисленное деление!

        if (a[m] < val) {
            l = m + 1;
        } else if (a[m] > val) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return l;
 }
```

Получив индекс, сравните значение с элементом по этому индексу. Если не равны, то значение отсутствует, и следующий бинарный поиск начинайте именно с этого индекса (при сортированном первом массиве).

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    namespace TEST
    {
        class Program
        {
        static int[] BubbleSort(int[] mas) //сортировка пузырьком
        {
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < mas.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (mas[i] > mas[j])
                    {
                        temp = mas[i];
                        mas[i] = mas[j];
                        mas[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return mas;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) //двоичный поиск, по заданию 
        {
            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            int mas_size = 10, m, lowerBound, upperBound;
            int[] a = new int[mas_size];
            int[] b = new int[mas_size];
            int[] c = new int[mas_size];
            int last_zap = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                a[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
                b[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }
            time.Start();
            a = BubbleSort(a);
            b = BubbleSort(b);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                lowerBound = 0;
                upperBound = mas_size;
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    if (c[last_zap - 1] == a[j])
                        continue;
                }
 
                while (true) //проблемная часть
                {
                    m = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                    if ((m < 0) || (m > mas_size - 1))
                        break;
                    if (a[j] < b[m])
                        upperBound = upperBound - 1;
                    else if (a[j] > b[m])
                        lowerBound = lowerBound + 1;
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
 
                    if (lowerBound > upperBound || m == 0)
                    {
                        c[last_zap] = a[j];
                        last_zap++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            time.Stop(); //установить время работы программы, по заданию
            Console.WriteLine("Продолжительность работы: " + time.Elapsed);
            if (mas_size <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("a[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, a[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("b[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, b[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n Элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В:\n");
                    for (int j = 0; j < last_zap; j++)
                    {
                        if (c[j] != 0) { Console.Write(c[j] + " "); };
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\nНе соответствуют условию\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
     static void Main(string[] args) //двоичный поиск, по заданию 
        {
            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            Random Rnd = new Random();
            int mas_size = 10, m, lowerBound, upperBound;
            int[] a = new int[mas_size];
            int[] b = new int[mas_size];
            int[] c = new int[mas_size];
            int last_zap = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                a[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
                b[j] = Rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }
            time.Start();
            a = BubbleSort(a);
            b = BubbleSort(b);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                lowerBound = 0;
                upperBound = mas_size;
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    if (c[last_zap - 1] == a[j])
                        continue;
                }
 
                while (true) //проблемная часть
                {
                    m = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
                    if ((m < 0) || (m > mas_size - 1))
                        break;
                    if (a[j] < b[m])
                        upperBound = upperBound - 1;
                    else if (a[j] > b[m])
                        lowerBound = lowerBound + 1;
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
 
                    if (lowerBound > upperBound || m == 0)
                    {
                        c[last_zap] = a[j];
                        last_zap++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            time.Stop(); //установить время работы программы, по заданию
            Console.WriteLine("Продолжительность работы: " + time.Elapsed);
            if (mas_size <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("a[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, a[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("b[{0}] = {1};", j + 1, b[j]);
                    if (j % 10 == 9) Console.WriteLine();
                }
                if (last_zap > 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n Элементы, которые присутствуют в массиве А, но отсутствуют в массиве В:\n");
                    for (int j = 0; j < last_zap; j++)
                    {
                        if (c[j] != 0) { Console.Write(c[j] + " "); };
                    }
                }
             else        
                    Console.WriteLine("\nНе соответствуют условию\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что это за фрагмент неотформатированного кода, что он делает?